# VSDBCMD generates an error when running in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, schema-compare, vsdbcmd

We are running VSDBCMD to generate a diff sql script between our database project and our staging database. VSDBCMD is executed locally on staging server and is started by a powershell script from a remote host. When running the script locally (starting it manually) it runs and generates a diff script, but when running remote we've got the following output:

TSD00560 The project and target databases have different collation settings. Deployment errors might occur.
TSD00566 Deployment script generated to: path\CURRENT_RELEASE.sql

An unexpected failure occurred: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Schema.Sql.Sql100UserInteractionServices' threw an exception.

We've tried to run the powershell script with different execution policys but with no success.

What is Sql100UserInteractionServices used for? Why is it throwing an exception when run from a powershell script executed remotely?

Comment: When running remotely fails, follow the remoting troubleshooting guidance - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347642.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found that dll file Microsoft.Data.Schema.Sql.dll on my staging server was an older version than the one that existed on my developer computer. By copying all the files from my local folder Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VSTSDB\Deploy to the stagingserver the error didn't occur any more.